# How to setup git to raise an error when certain text gets pushed or commited?

Tags: git

When working with code, I often put there "temporary" stuff, comment things out, etc., marking such things like this:

```
DO NOT CHECK IT IN
```

The problem is, such temporary sections often end up pushed to master.
Is there a way to script git, so it would detect such text getting pushed (or commited), and raise an error or a warning?

Comment: Read about using Git hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `pre-push` or `pre-commit` git hooks https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks ?